# Advantages of numerical differentiation?

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, numerical-methods

Excuse the rather broad and soft question, but what exactly are the advantages of numerical differentiation.

The error of the $n$-th derivative must be really high relative to the $\Delta x$.

So why would anyone differentiate numerically instead of analytically (through parsing and deriving the derivatives), other than the fast implementation of the numerical differentiation ?

Comment: This question is a bit refreshing; it seems more common for people ask the opposite: "Why bother with all this theory when I can just compute a difference quotient with a small value of $h$?"

Comment: If you apply a Chebyshev transform to your function, and differentiate the resulting Chebyshev polynomial, the error is not high. This is the standard method of doing numerical differentiation.

Answer (score 4):

I think the basic answer is that not all functions are in closed form.  You may need the derivative of a function that is only known as the result of a very complicated procedure, or a "black box" whose code you don't have access to.